# Categorize the output of ec2-describe-images or ec2-describe-instances

Tags: scripting, data-processing

Is there any command/tool/script to categorize the bulky output of `ec2-describe-images` or `ec2-describe-instances`.

I have a list of around 100 servers with each and every detail. I want to categorize them under suitable headings like - `RESERVATION`, `INSTANCE`, `BLOCKDEVICE`, `TAG` (whatever category is available on the output).

Comment: Please give an example of `ec2-describe-images` output. 
We will also appreciate if you can report here the response of the same question you posted on http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=4574853#post4574853

Answer (score 1):

Did you get this sorted? If not...

run ec2-describe-images with the option **--headers** to give you the categories

```
ec2-describe-images --private-key ~/private.key --cert ~/my.crt --region us-west-1 --headers
```

if you just want certain fields then just pipe the output of the above through the linux command **cut** picking the fields (columns) you are after. Say you want ImageID, Name and Architecture then these would be fields 2,3 and 8 of the output above. Example.

```
 ec2-describe-images --private-key ~/private.key --cert ~/my.crt --region us-west-1 --headers | cut -f2,3,8 -s
```

Doing the same for ec2-describe-instances would be similar.

Answer (score 0):

It's a job for `awk` (or `perl`, `python` or other general purpose scripting language).

`awk` can handle records with various record/field length, can create associative arrays, and it's a reporting language, which is usually installed on every *nix.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile:

```
ez-ec2-describe-instances() {
    ec2-describe-instances $* --headers | egrep '(ReservationID|running|pending)'|cut -f 2,3,4,6,7,10,12; 
}
```

Logout/login or run ". ~/.bashrc". Then you can use:

```
$ ez-ec2-describe-instances 
ReservationID   Owner   Groups
i-6f194113  ami-1624987f    ec2-107-20-75-13.compute-1.amazonaws.com    running t1.micro    us-east-1a
```

You can pass arguments to ez-ec2-describe-instances, just like you would pass them to the regular ec2-describe-instances. E.g.:

```
$ ez-ec2-describe-instances --region eu-west-1
ReservationID   Owner   Groups
i-e4fd6eaf  ami-c37474b7    ec2-54-246-38-35.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com    pending t1.micro    eu-west-1a
```